# objective C save file with extension and name to dictonary

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

I have a browse function where I get the url of a file.

Now I want to save the file in the supporting file dictionary so that if the file is move anywhere else it can still access it

I have a code which saves it to the supporting files:

```
NSURL *mainUrl;
mainUrl=[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
NSFileManager *Fm;
[Fm copyItemAtURL:url toURL:mainUrl error:nil];
```

but I don't know what the name and the extension because the browse function allows png,jpg,jepg files

and I would need the name to access it

so my question would be how I can I save the file there with a name and extension of my choose

my name would look like that:

```
NSString *string;
NSInteger number;
number=0;
string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%li",@"img",(long)number];
```

and the extension would be jpg

can somebody help me?

Comment: This doesn't make sense; how can you be copying files into your bundle?  Also if you want to track file moves then you need to use bookmarks: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:error:

Comment: If your only fear is the file moving, wouldn't keeping an alias to the file better than copying the file? (Aliases track files when they move)  Duplication of data is a sure way of getting sync problems (user changes file, but then moves the file; your copy would be out-of-date)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSString`'s `-stringByAppendingPathExtension:` method:

```
[@"foo" stringByAppendingPathExtension: @"jpg"];
```

results in `@"foo.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the file name and the extension using the specified full path and the following functions.

/* NSString Class References*/

lastPathComponent
Returns the last path component of the receiver.

- (NSString *)lastPathComponent

pathExtension
Interprets the receiver as a path and returns the receiver’s extension, if any.

- (NSString *)pathExtension